# What is the correct way to share plugins for programs within a super build?

Tags: c++, cmake

Take the following example sturcture of a project:

```
.
+-- CMakeLists.txt
+-- app1
|   +-- CMakeLists.txt
+-- app2
|   +-- CMakeLists.txt
+-- app3
|   +-- CMakeLists.txt
+-- plugins
|   +-- plugin1
|       +-- CMakeLists.txt
|   +-- plugin2
|       +-- CMakeLists.txt
|   +-- plugin3
|       +-- CMakeLists.txt
+-- tests
|   +-- CMakeLists.txt
```

Now all appX and tests need all plugins under plugins. (on windows: incl. the needed dlls of the plugins into the executable dir). Note that I can't modify the source code to fit the build system.

My naive way is to just copy each plugin after the build step into each app dir. But this feels so unmaintainable and "not the right way to do it".

Is there some buildin support for these kind of operations?

Comment: Set the path environment variable?

Comment: The project uses hard-coded paths (relative to the executable) to search for plugins. An env paths does not work

Comment: not clear what you are asking: for tests, if the dependency is declared and tests are linked against those libs, it should already work. For AppX itself, what are your install directives? you may put all app together with libs so I don't see any pb. Can you elaborate and give code?

Comment: all projects under plugins are dlls(on windows) which get loaded at runtime from the user if he needs these. Therefore they are not directly linked in the cmake but they might be loaded at runtime. 

More in my anwer which solves this for me currently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now wrote a script which utilises https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/BundleUtilities.html which got run at build and install time. All plugins which are configured to build are added to a list which will be used to copy the needed dlls into the executable dir. `fixup_bundle(all_executables all_plugins additional_dirs)`

at build time this gets more complex since each executable has its own dir. so a loop `fixup_bundle(current_executable all_plugins additional_dirs)` is needed. This however takes a lot of processing power and time to resolve all. (as stated in the documentation too) so it will only be run if the developer needs it.

It isn't the best solution but since the functionalities could be bundled into a script it is maintainable and most of the functionality comes directly from cmake itself.

I will post the link to the scripts as soon as the PR is merged (so that a permalink could be used)